# Guzzle 6.3 Async Pool: Updating the list of Pool requests from inside a fulfilled promise callback?

Tags: php, asynchronous, guzzle

I'm working on a process where I have a *Queue*, and I start with a known unit of work. As I process the unit of work, it will result in *zero-or-more* (unknown) units of work that gets added to the *Queue*. I continue to process the queue until there's no more work to perform.

I'm working on a *proof-of-concept* using Guzzle where I accept a first URL to seed the queue, then process the body of the response which *may* result in more URLs that need to be processed. My goal is to add them to the queue and have Guzzle continue processing them until there's nothing left in the queue.

In other cases, I can define a variable as the queue, and pass it by-reference into a function so that it gets updated with new work. But in the case of Guzzle Async Pools (which I *think* is the most efficient way to handle this), there doesn't seem to be a clear way to update the queue in-process and have the Pool execute the requests.

Does Guzzle provide a built-in approach for updating the list of Pool requests from inside a fulfilled *Promise* callback?

```php
use ArrayIterator;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise\EachPromise;
use GuzzleHttp\TransferStats;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

// Re-usable callback which prints the URL being requested
function onStats(TransferStats $stats) {
    echo sprintf(
        '%s (%s)' . PHP_EOL,
        $stats->getEffectiveUri(),
        $stats->getTransferTime()
    );
}

// The queue of work to be performed
$requests = new ArrayIterator([
    $client->get('http://httpbin.org/anything', [
        'on_stats' => 'onStats',
    ])
]);

// Process the queue, which results in more work to be performed
$p = (new EachPromise($requests, [
    'concurrency' => 50,
    'fulfilled'   => function(ResponseInterface $response) use ($client, &$requests) {
        $hash = bin2hex(random_bytes(10));
        $requests[] = $client->get(sprintf('http://httpbin.org/anything/%s', $hash), [
            'on_stats' => 'onStats',
        ]);
    },
    'rejected' => function($reason) {
        echo $reason . PHP_EOL;
    },
]))->promise();

// Wait for everything to finish
$p->wait(true);
```

My question appears to be similar to [Incrementally add requests to a Guzzle 5.0 Pool (Rolling Requests)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105093/incrementally-add-requests-to-a-guzzle-5-0-pool-rolling-requests), but is different in that these refer to different major versions of Guzzle.

Answer (score 1):

After posting this, I was able to do more searching and found some more SO threads and GitHub Issues for Guzzle. I found this library, which appears to address the problem.

https://github.com/alexeyshockov/guzzle-dynamic-pool

Comment: Hi, I'm Alex, author of the library. Feel free to ask questions about it :)

Comment: Thanks Alex. Looking at your code helped me understand what I needed to do differently.